# Finding the intersection between two series in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, series, intersection

I have two series `s1` and `s2` in pandas and want to compute the intersection i.e. where all of the values of the series are common.

How would I use the `concat` function to do this? I have been trying to work it out but have been unable to (I don't want to compute the intersection on the indices of `s1` and `s2`, but on the values).

Comment: An example would be helpful to clarify what you're looking for - e.g. are you doing element-wise sets for a group of columns, or sets of all unique values along a column? I guess folks think the latter, using e.g. the example in the answer by eldad-a.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Place both series in Python's [set container](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) then use the set intersection method:

```
s1.intersection(s2)
```

and then transform back to list if needed.

Just noticed pandas in the tag. Can translate back to that:

```
pd.Series(list(set(s1).intersection(set(s2))))
```

From comments I have changed this to a more Pythonic expression, which is shorter and easier to read:

```
Series(list(set(s1) & set(s2)))
```

should do the trick, except if the index data is also important to you.

Have added the `list(...)` to translate the set before going to pd.Series as pandas does not accept a set as direct input for a Series.

Comment: also, you can use `&` operator for set intersection.

Comment: Actually, you can't just apply Series to a set (which is annoying) `TypeError: Set value is unordered`, seems unnecessary restriction/not very duck.

Comment: Mmm.  used same logic while ago, but I probably moved it to list 1st... short calc so performance was not a major constraint.   What it the syntax for using the & operator to do the set?

Comment: `set(s1) & set(s2)` :)

Comment: ahh.. thought the & was in pandas

Comment: FYI, can also do: ``s1[s1.isin(s2)]``, my timings show about the same perf

Comment: You need ``Series(list(set(s1) & set(s2)))`` as the set result is unordered

Comment: ``isin`` keeps the ordering the same as s1, and somewhat faster on really large series

Comment: @Jeff that was a considerably slower for me on the small example, but may make up for it with larger... drop_duplicates is *really* slow.

Comment: its better for > 100k elements (but dependeds on the density of matches too for some reason)....

Comment: no need to convert `s2` to a `set`; `pd.Series(list(set(s1).intersection(s2)))` works (at least in pandas 0.25)

Answer (score 50):

Setup:

```
s1 = pd.Series([4,5,6,20,42])
s2 = pd.Series([1,2,3,5,42])
```

Timings:

```
%%timeit
pd.Series(list(set(s1).intersection(set(s2))))
10000 loops, best of 3: 57.7 µs per loop

%%timeit
pd.Series(np.intersect1d(s1,s2))
1000 loops, best of 3: 659 µs per loop

%%timeit
pd.Series(np.intersect1d(s1.values,s2.values))
10000 loops, best of 3: 64.7 µs per loop
```

So the numpy solution can be comparable to the set solution even for small series, if one uses the `values` explicitly.

Comment: redid test with newest numpy(1.8.1) and pandas (0.14.1) looks like your second example is now comparible in timeing to others.   With larger data your last method is a clear winner 3 times faster than others

Comment: It's because the second one is 1000 loops and the rest are 10000 loops

Answer (score 23):

If you are using Pandas, I assume you are also using NumPy. NumPy has a function `intersect1d` that will work with a Pandas series.

Example:

```
pd.Series(np.intersect1d(pd.Series([1,2,3,5,42]), pd.Series([4,5,6,20,42])))
```

will return a Series with the values 5 and 42.

Comment: FYI This is orders of magnitude slower that set. :(

Comment: For shame. @AndyHayden Is there a reason we can't add set ops to `Series` objects?

Comment: Thanks, @AndyHayden. I had just naively assumed numpy would have faster ops on arrays. A quick `%timeit` test shows you to be _mostly_ correct. My method had an average of 775 us per loop on two Series of 100 randomly generated elements whereas @joop's method had 120 us per loop. However, for larger data sets, this relationship is reversed. On two sets of 100000 elements, my method showed 1.32 ms per loop and @joop's method showed 14.9 ms per loop.

Comment: very interesting, fyi @cpcloud opened an issue here https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4480

Comment: @jbn see my answer for how to get the numpy solution with comparable timing for short series as well.

Answer (score 16):

Python

```
s1 = pd.Series([4,5,6,20,42])
s2 = pd.Series([1,2,3,5,42])

s1[s1.isin(s2)]
```

R

```
s1  <- c(4,5,6,20,42)
s2 <- c(1,2,3,5,42)

s1[s1 %in% s2]
```

**Edit:** Doesn't handle dupes.

Comment: It won't handle duplicates correctly, at least the R code, don't know about python. In R there is `intersect` function, and for data.frame/data.table use `fintersect`.

Answer (score 7):

[**`pd.merge`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) can be used:

```
pd.merge(series1, series2, how='inner').drop_duplicates()
```

Note that the result is a dataframe.

Comment: Not anymore, as of v0.24.

Comment: for anyone interested - in Dask it won't work, this solution will return AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution by checking both left and right inclusions

```py
import pandas as pd

def intersect(left, right):
    left, right = pd.Series(pd.unique(left)), pd.Series(pd.unique(right))
    right = right.loc[right.isin(left)]
    left  =  left.loc[left.isin(right)]
    return pd.Series(pd.unique(left))

left = pd.Series([1,2,pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA], index=[*"abcde"], dtype="Int32")
right = pd.Series([pd.NA, pd.NA, 1, 3], index=[*"efgh"], dtype="Int32")
intersect(left, right)
```

**This has 2 major advantages:**

- It works with [pandas Int32](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html) and other nullable data types. If your columns contain `pd.NA` then `np.intersect1d` throws an error!
- It keeps the pandas dtype intact

Comment: you don't need the second line in this function