# How to get the Intersection and Union of two Series in Pandas with non-unique values?

Tags: python, pandas, minhash

If I have 2 Series objects, like so: [0,0,1] [1,0,0]
How would I get the intersection and union of the two?
They only contain booleans which means they are non-unique values.

I have a large Boolean matrix. I've minhashed it and now I'm trying to find the false positives and negatives which I think means that I have to get the Jaccard similarity for each original pair.

Comment: For intersection, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18079695/2799941).

Comment: Does that work with non-unique values?

Comment: And if they are boolean then then Whats the use of intersection and union.  Are you just trying to recreate `&` and `|`. Curious, why do you need intresection over booleans?

Comment: Yes I am. I'm just trying to do it for an large dataset.

Comment: Why? Whats the need for that? Can you specify that, so we can come with a much better answer for your actual problem.

Comment: I have a large Boolean matrix. I've minhashed it and now I'm trying to find the false positives and negatives which I think means that I have to get the Jaccard similarity for each original pair.

Comment: Add the same in your question. Also add expected output for your current input. For jaccard similartiy take a look here http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.jaccard_similarity_score.html

Comment: Is the data 1D or 2D ?

Comment: I'm extracting by each column so it's 1D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say they are booleans use `logical_and` and `logical_or` of numpy or `&` and `|` on series i.e

```
y1 = pd.Series([1,0,1,0])
y2 = pd.Series([1,0,0,1])

# Numpy approach 
intersection = np.logical_and(y1.values, y2.values)
union = np.logical_or(y1.values, y2.values)
intersection.sum() / union.sum()
# 0.33333333333333331

# Pandas approach 
sum(y1 & y2) / sum(y1 | y2)
# 0.33333333333333331
```

Comment: Thanks. Although this is the answer it's way too slow.

Comment: Whats the length of the arrays?

Comment: Each array is exactly 6000. And there are 1000 of them.

Comment: well numpy should take less time. It takes 16 micro secords for small array comparatively it should take less time.

Comment: I'm going to try and parallelize this.