# Pandas - how to compare 2 series and append the values which are in both to a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have written code where I have a dataframe containing all types of food. I have then split it into fruit and veg series using str.contains. I have written code where I append any food which is common in both series to a list:

```
fruit = fruit_2.tolist()#converting the series to a list
veg = veg_2.tolist()#converting the series to a list

for x in range (len(fruit)):
    for y in range (len(veg)):
        if fruit[x] == veg[y]:
            both.append(fruit[x]) 
print(both)
```

This works just wondering if someone has a solution which utilised pandas and doesn't use a for loop.
Thanks

Comment: Combine the two series and do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657241/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-duplicate-items-using-pandas-in-python

Comment: isin would be enough

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the intersection between two series in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18079563/finding-the-intersection-between-two-series-in-pandas)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement 'in' and 'not in' for Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960077/how-to-implement-in-and-not-in-for-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
fruit_2[fruit_2.isin(veg_2)]
```

This will give you the common elements.

Comment: The list is longer than I expected as it returns more values than my previous code, would you say my code is incorrect?.

Comment: No, I think the duplicates are filtered out. If you want to check just to be sure, just do this `c=fruit_2[fruit_2.isin(veg_2)]` and `len(c[c.duplicated(keep=False)]`

Comment: The length reutrns 0 when i run this, does this mean there are no duplicates?

Comment: Yep. No duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `np.intersect1d`

```
import numpy as np

# gives a numpy array (you can later convert to series or list)
both = np.intersect1d(fruit_2, veg_2)
```

courtesy of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18079563/finding-the-intersection-between-two-series-in-pandas/18080142#18080142)

Comment: I think this works, what is the syntax to convert this to a series?

Comment: `both_series = pd.Series(both)`