# Compare multiple columns in two dataframes and select rows with differing values

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to compare 2 columns in one dataframe(df1) with 2 columns in another dataframe(df2). After comparison, I want to select the rows where the first two columns do not match. You can see my attempts below and this what the dataframes look like [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqD1i.png)]

```
import pandas as pd

fd1= 'Q37.xlsx'
fd2= 'Q43.xlsx'
df1 = pd.read_excel( fd1, sheetname='prio 1') 
df2 = pd.read_excel( fd2, sheetname='prio 1')


closed_items= {} #items in fd1 but not in fd2
new_items={}  #items in fd2 but not in fd1
```

In order to get closed_items, I've tried the following 3 things

```
closed_items.where(df1[df1['Code'].values!=df2[df2['Code'].values and 
                   df1['Owner'].values != key in df1['Owner'].values)
```

and gotten

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

I've also tried

```
Closed_items = df2.loc[(df2['Code'] != df1['Code']) and 
               df2.loc[(df2['Owner'] != df1['Owner'])]
```

And lastly I tried

```
for key in df1['Code'].values:
    if key in df1['Code'].values != key in df1['Code'].values or key in 
              df1['Owner'].values != key in df1['Owner'].values:

          closed_items.append()
     else:
           pass
```

Which gave this syntax

```
 The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. 
 Use a.any() or a.all()
```

...

```
AFP= pd.ExcelWriter("AFP.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')

closed_items.to_excel(AFP, sheet_name='Closed', index=False)
```

Comment: I would think better is to have equally shaped series and try to use something like not s1.intersection(s2) or difference
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18079563/finding-the-intersection-between-two-series-in-pandas
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that df1 and df2 are of different shapes hence the loc will not work.
You first need to merge df1 and df2 like

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2,on='common_key',how='left',suffixes=('_df1','_df2'))
            df3['select'] = 0
df3.loc[(df3['Code_df1'] == df3['Code_df2']) & 
                           (df3.loc[(df3['Owner_df1'] == df3['Owner_df2']),'select'])] = 1

df3.loc[df3['select']==0,:]
```

will return wherever they do not match

Comment: It returns Invalid syntax on 

df3.loc[(df3['Code_df1'] == df3['Code_df2']) & df3.loc[(df3['Owner_df1'] == df3['Owner_df2']),'select'] = 1

Comment: Use this I missed a closing parenthesis while copying the code. 
df3.loc[(df3['Code_df1'] == df3['Code_df2']) & 
                   (df3.loc[(df3['Owner_df1'] == df3['Owner_df2']),'select'])] = 1