# If text is contained in another dataframe then flag row with a binary designation

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on mining survey data. I was able to flag the rows for certain keywords:

```
survey['Rude'] = survey['Comment Text'].str.contains('rude', na=False, regex=True).astype(int)
```

Now, I want to flag any rows containing names. I have another dataframe that contains common US names. 
Here's what I thought would work, but it is not flagging any rows, and I have validated that names do exist in the 'Comment Text'

```
for row in survey:   
    for word in survey['Comment Text']:
        survey['Name'] = 0
        if word in names['Name']:
            survey['Name'] = 1
```

Comment: Which has more rows, the list of names, or the survey?

Comment: The survey df has 38,000 rows and the names df has 20,000 rows.

Comment: Is comment text a string or list of words? Can you provide example input and output?

Comment: Is the `==` in `survey['Name'] == 1` just a typo in your post?

Comment: Comment text examples:
Example 1: Lines were long, didn't have the product I was looking for.

Example 2: Very friendly staffVery clean inside and outAlways seem to have enough staff

Comment: @AMC great catch! I changed it to = instead of ==. It still does not work though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not looping through the series correctly.  `for row in survey:` loops through the column names in `survey`. `for word in survey['Comment Text']:` loops though the comment strings. `survey['Name'] = 0` creates a column of all `0s`.

You could use [set intersections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18079563/finding-the-intersection-between-two-series-in-pandas) and [apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), to avoid all the looping through rows:

```
    survey = pd.DataFrame({'Comment_Text':['Hi rcriii',
                                           'Hi yourself stranger',
                                           'say hi to Justin for me']})
    names = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['rcriii', 'Justin', 'Susan', 'murgatroyd']})
    s2 = set(names['Name'])

    def is_there_a_name(s):
        s1 = set(s.split())
        if len(s1.intersection(s2))>0:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

    survey['Name'] = survey['Comment_Text'].apply(is_there_a_name)

    print(names)
    print(survey)

         Name
0      rcriii
1      Justin
2       Susan
3  murgatroyd
              Comment_Text  Name
0                Hi rcriii     1
1     Hi yourself stranger     0
2  say hi to Justin for me     1
```

As a bonus, return `len(s1.intersection(s2))` to get the number of matches per line.

Comment: Thank you so much!